# Call async method on background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a background thread that will from then on execute asynchronously. This is in a MVC 5 Web Application.

So in the code below I check if the data is in cache, and if so return that data, but then create a background thread, which then makes a call to the database, and when this data is returned from the database (done in an async way) then set the data in the cache. So the next calls to the server from the client will get the updated cached data. Next step is using SignalR to automatically update the client with the cached data, but I'm not there yet.

So what's happening in my code below is if the cache has the data, then a background thread is created, but the thread never gets passed this line in the GetData method:

```
await SetDataInner();
```

Any help with getting it so execution in the background thread can continue after that SetDataInner() resolves?

*Note: I know this is a strange set up but the database returns data in so much time that I've been forced to implement a strategy like this to at least show cached data to the user until the database eventually returns with data. I know what you're thinking, the database should be fixed to return data quicker, and yes that's the long-term goal, but I need something like this working in the mean time.

Thanks for your help!

My code:

```
public async Task SetStuff(string cacheKey)
{
  var data = CacheHelper.Get(cacheKey) as Model;
  if (data != null)
  {
    Task.Run(() => SetData());          
    return;
  }

  // Set user info
  await SetData();
```

}

```
private async Task SetData()
{
  await SetDataInner();
}
```

Comment: await clause's purpose is to cause the current thread to wait until the other tasks are done. If you want the thread to continue it's work, just remove it. The tasks will keep on running.

Comment: what does `SetData1` through `SetData3` do?

Comment: @InbarBarkai No, that's not how `async/await` works at all. A continuation of the rest of the method is constructed and when whatever it is that is being awaited completes, the continuation is queued for execution using the SynchronizationContext that was current at the time of the await. If this doesn't happen, there is likely no SynchronizationContext in play.

Comment: If you're doing asynchronous programming you likely don't need a background thread.  The idea is that an async call does not block the current thread while IO (in this case your DB calls) is done and allows it to handle other tasks until the IO is done.  With that said your current code just needs to `await` the result of your `Task.Run` call.

Comment: `await` does not make any thread wait, instead it will either return the result from the awaited task (if it has already completed) or return with a task that encapsulates the continuation. What the calling code then does depends on the calling code.

Comment: Shouldn't `Task.Run(() => SetData());` be `await Task.Run(() => SetData());`?

Comment: I would recommend not mixing threads and tasks. Stick with tasks.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I know that it doesn't actually pauses the thread, I just think that this is the easiest way to understand what happens when you use async/await.

Comment: I disagree. Multithreaded programming is one of those things you simply cannot wing, you need to really understand what is happening. Cudos to Microsoft for building support for it into the language but we shouldn't believe it is all magical. Before you know it people will be stuffing `Application.DoEvents` into nooks and crannies to get things going again. But that is neither here nor there, nothing that explains the behavior the OP is having so I believe this discussion is for another time and place :)

Comment: What kind of application is this? Winforms? WPF? Console? Web?

Comment: @juharr I'm trying to write code to immediately return to the caller if the cache has the data, but set the cache with new data in the background (i.e. a background thread?). So in this case I don't want to await the task.Run line of code because i want to immediately return execution to the caller.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 1. ```Application.DoEvents``` LOL. 
2. Threading is complex to some people, especially newbies. I agree that you need to know what you are using, but if I would follow this mind, I would send most people who ask questions here to google thoroughly the tools they are using and I don't think that that is SO purpose.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen This is an MVC Web Application.

Comment: @slawekwin SetData1 and SetData2 are calling async methods to eventually retrieve data from the database.

Comment: Are you doing properly in the outer calls? If the outer calls are not aware of the fact that your responses are continuing asynchronously the response is likely prepared and sent back before those have executed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So the code works just fine if the cache doesn't have the data, meaning all of the async code works as intended. The issue seems to be that I'm mixing tasks and async awaits like you mentioned. The outer calls are aware the code in the lower levels is asynchronous and use the await keyword. Perhaps this code will never work? I basically want to execute the code in the traditional async approach if the cache doesn't have the data, and only use something like Task.Run to set the cache with new data in the background if the cache actually has data.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I see that the background thread doesn't even return a response to the caller and just gets stuck at the Task.WhenAll line of code. Note this scenario only occurs when the cache has data. When the cache doesn't have data then everything works just fine.

Comment: @jre247: I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted. Try reducing your actual code to the [minimum necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StephenCleary The code above actually reproduces the problem. It seems that you can't mix async code inside a background thread. If I create a synchronous version of the SetData method, without any awaits, then the background thread can execute all that code no problem. But when I have the awaits there the background thread seems to bomb out.

Comment: @StephenCleary I updated the question code to be more clear and reproducible.

Comment: @jre247: I've used `async` code on background threads **tons** of times without any trouble. The problem you're having is in code that isn't posted. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - with particular note of the C ("Complete", as in, "I can copy/paste this into my own Visual Studio and reproduce the problem").

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary I will get that code to you tomorrow morning. Appreciate your help!